# Sorting in Kotlin

Tags: sorting, kotlin, comparator, comparable

I have a problem with sorting objects in Kotlin. I have class

`Home(id : String, name : String)`

and I would like to sort it first by name and then by ids, where ids can be:

- numbers like 1,2,3,10,
- numbers with string: 1a, 10-14.

This solution does not provide the correct result. Please not that ids are String so the result I'm getting is `-> 1, 10, 2, 3`

`myList = myList?.sortedWith(compareBy<Home> { it.name }.thenBy { it.id })`

How to add in `then.by` correct comparator, or how it should be sorted?

Greetings

@EDIT
I found a solution, but how to add it in `thenBy`?

```
    Collections.sort(strings, object : Comparator<String> {
        override fun compare(o1: String, o2: String): Int {
            return extractInt(o1) - extractInt(o2)
        }

        fun extractInt(s: String): Int {
            val num = s.replace("\\D".toRegex(), "")
            // return 0 if no digits found
            return if (num.isEmpty()) 0 else Integer.parseInt(num)
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data class Person(
    val name: String,
    var id: String
)

fun sortPersonsWithParsedIds() {
    val p1 = Person("abc", "2")
    val p2 = Person("abc", "1")
    val p3 = Person("xyz", "10kafsd")
    val p4 = Person("xyz", "1asda")
    val p5 = Person("pqr", "2aaa")
    val p6 = Person("pqr", "20")
    val p7 = Person("pqr", "20aa")

    val list = listOf(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7)

    val sortedList = list.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.name }, { v -> extractInt(v.id) }))

    sortedList.forEach { println(it) }
}

private fun extractInt(s: String): Int {
    val num = s.replace("\\D".toRegex(), "")
    // return 0 if no digits found
    return if (num.isEmpty()) 0 else Integer.parseInt(num)
}
```

**Result:**

```
Person(name=abc, id=1)
Person(name=abc, id=2)
Person(name=pqr, id=2aaa)
Person(name=pqr, id=20)
Person(name=pqr, id=20aa)
Person(name=xyz, id=1asda)
Person(name=xyz, id=10kafsd)
```

Comment: Thank you :) Maybe you know how also add an id like ```2-10``` with regex and then put it between ```2 and 2aaa```?

Answer (score 2):

Just

```
myList?.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.name }, { extractInt(it.id) }))
```

Comment: Thank you :) Maybe you know how also add an id like 2-10 with regex and then put it between 2 and 2aaa?

Comment: @CallMePedro create a separate question

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the comparable interface using an object declaration and put there the logic to compare both strings, this way you can use it in the thenBy clause:

```
val myList= myList?.sortedWith(compareBy<Home> { it.name }.thenBy {
 object: Comparable<String>{
     override fun compareTo(other: String): Int {
         return extractInt(it.id) - extractInt(other)
     }

    fun extractInt(s: String): Int {
        val num = s.replace("\\D".toRegex(), "")
        // return 0 if no digits found
        return if (num.isEmpty()) 0 else Integer.parseInt(num)
    }
}
```

})

Answer (score 1):

It would be `.thenBy { extractInt(it.id) }` (where you declare `extractInt` separately). Or just put the definition of `extractInt` there if that's the only place you need it:

```
compareBy<Home> { it.name }.thenBy { 
    val num = it.id.replace("\\D".toRegex(), "")
    // return 0 if no digits found
    if (num.isEmpty()) 0 else Integer.parseInt(num)
}
```

Of course, these solutions will consider e.g. `10` and `10a` or `as` and `0` to be equal; is that really what you want? If not, you can return a pair of the extracted integer part and the remaining string.

Comment: I would like to put them in order : ```1, 1a, 1f, 2d, 2j, 2-10, 3, 4, 12```